# does openssl support RSASSA-PPS ,RSA EMSA-PSS encoding?

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, signature

I need to create the signature of the data string using SHA256 HASH function and RSASSA-PSS with RSA EMSA-PSS encoding.does openssl support this..?

i am creating signature using the API

```
int RSA_sign_ASN1_OCTET_STRING(int type,const unsigned char *m, 
                                unsigned int m_length,unsigned char *sigret, 
                                unsigned int*siglen, RSA *rsa);
```

and

```
int RSA_verify_ASN1_OCTET_STRING(int type,const unsigned char *m, 
                                 unsigned int _length,unsigned char *sigbuf, 
                                 unsigned int siglen, RSA *rsa);
```

i am not sure which Padding technique and encoding methos it is using default.. can any one tell what is the default methods its using and will it support the RSASSA-PSS and RSA EMSA-pss

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it supports PSS padding, take a look at RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_PSS function, and this link: http://fixunix.com/openssl/526614-signing-verifying-messages-rsassa-pss.html